# Why afIoc doesn't inject the service in this case?

Tags: fantom

I'm trying to create a very simple app using the IoC framework for Fantom [afIoc](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/) to become familiar with it. I tried this...

```
using afIoc

class Main {
  Registry registry := IocService([AppModule#]).start.registry

  @Inject
  myPod::Version? version

  Void main() {
    echo("version is $version")
  }    
}
```

The Version class is

```
const class Version {
  override Str toStr() {
    "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

The AppModule is

```
using afIoc

class AppModule {
  static Void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(myPod::Version#)
  }
}
```

It compiles but prints `version is null`. I fixed the problem by redefining my Main class:

```
using afIoc

class Main {

  Registry registry := IocService([AppModule#]).start.registry

  Void main() {
    version := (myPod::Version) registry.serviceById("myPod::Version")
    echo("version is $version")
  }
}
```

But I'd like to understand the lifecycle of the afIoc Registry and why the Version service is not injected in my first version of the Main class. Can anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people ask similar questions of other IoC frameworks... So lets look at what happens when you run the program:

```java
using afIoc

class Main {  //................................................... 1
  Registry registry := IocService([AppModule#]).start.registry //.. 2

  @Inject
  myPod::Version? version //....................................... 3

  Void main() {
    echo("version is $version") //................................. 4
  }    
}
```

1. Fantom instantiates the `Main` class.
2. Fantom creates the `registry` field and assigns it to the result of `IocService([AppModule#]).start.registry`. This statement simply builds and returns the IoC registry.
3. Fantom creates the `version` fields and defaults it to `null`.
4. Fantom calls the `main()` method which prints out the `version`, which is `null`.

Note that nowhere above have we asked IoC to *meddle* with our `Main` class. We just new'ed up the IoC Registry and set it to a field.

If we want the IoC to inject values into a class we have to ask it to:

```java
  Void main() {
    registry.injectIntoFields(this)

    echo("version is $version")  // --> version is 0.0.1
  }
```

Or we could ask IoC to instantiate a new instance of `Main` for us:

```java
registry.autobuild(Main#)
```

Note that many calls to `autobuild()` would create many instances of `Main`.

For IoC to only create one instance of `Main` (a singleton), define it as a service in `AppModule` and use `regsitry.serviceById()` or `registry.dependencyByType()` - much as you discovered with `Version`.